# How to change column width for different pages of your UWP App?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an app which has an App shell. Here I define a partition in the Page like this

```
<UserControl>
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have different pages in my app and each page maintains this partition. However, I do have a page which wants to change this partition to a different number

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

How would I achieve this without creating this partition for each page? The partition is in AppShell.xaml which has a corresponding ViewModel AppSHellViewModel. In addition each page has a view and a view model. How would i change the column width of the user control from another xaml view?

Answer (score 0):

> How would I achieve this without creating this partition for each page?

If you don't want to make Grid for each page and set dynamic partition number, you could generate the grid in the code behind like the following.

```
private Panel AddBaseLayout()
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();  
    ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
    ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
    ColumnDefinition col3 = new ColumnDefinition();
    col1.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
    col2.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
    col3.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col3);

    return grid;
}

RootGrid.Children.Add(AddBaseLayout());
```

> How would i change the column width of the user control from another xaml view?

You could make a dependency property for user control like the following.

```
public sealed partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public GridLength ColumnWidth
    {
        get { return (GridLength)GetValue(ColumnWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnWidth", typeof(GridLength), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));


}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{x:Bind ColumnWidth, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

**Usage**

```
<Grid x:Name="Test">
    <local:CustomControl ColumnWidth="400"/>
</Grid>
```